# How can I tell what command palette action is being executed on a VSCode dropdown helper action?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

This action here is behaving weirdly for me.

I'm not sure what he terminology is - but the dropdown menu you get as you type.

Is there a way to see what action or extension is being used to use this downdown action? I want to look at the documentation for it or whatever to see if it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this drop-down is issued by auto-completion,
offering you to complete the typed name, `Card`, to the other components of the
[Card React Component API](https://material-ui.com/api/card/).

These are [CardActionArea](https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/),
[CardActions](https://material-ui.com/api/card-actions/)
and the others, and also including all sort of other tags that
Visual Code thinks are related.

You are at liberty to click on one of them, which will replace the `Card`
tag by the clicked item, or type <kbd>Esc</kbd> which will close the list,
click anywhere else which will also close the list,
or continue typing after the `Card` which will refine your displayed options
in the drop-down list.

Auto-completion is very useful, but if it's bothering you, you may disable
it in the Options of Visual Code. It's generated by Visual Code itself
and not by any extension.